# How to save ALAssetsLibrary to usersDefault when i close my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When i save images in ALAssetsLibrary, it's ok to show them in my table, but when i close my app from multitasking bar - records is cleared. How to save them and stay load in my table when i run my app again???

I found this [Saving ALAsset URL in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554399/saving-alasset-url-in-nsuserdefaults?rq=1)

Comment: "The lifetimes of objects you get back from a library instance are tied to the lifetime of the library instance."  (ALAssetsLibrary class reference) which makes it sound difficult to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to save resources so that you can use them later. If it does, you can save the path of resource to your user defaults or core data, and store them into "Photo Album". When you need it, just use the path in string as the resource path to get it.

Take a look at [ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum](https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum/blob/dev/Demo/ALAssetsLibraryCustomPhotoAlbum_BasicDemo/ALAssetsLibraryCustomPhotoAlbum_BasicDemo/Controllers/PhotosTableViewController.m#L280), maybe you'll like it. ;)